# An interesting sequence that related to Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that $a_0=0, a_1=1$ and $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1} + a_{n}+ {{n} \choose {m}}$ for $m$ a fixed positive integer. Prove that
> $$\displaystyle a_{n}=F_{m+1}F_{n-1} + (F_{m+2}+1)F_n - \sum_{k=0}^{m} {n+k \choose m-k} $$
> where $F_n$ is the Fibonacci number.

I've tried several approaches but without any progress.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please show your work. "I've tried several approaches" don't says anything. If you don't tell us what have you tried we may be will be trying the same things you did, wasting our time...

Comment: First use $F_{m+1}F_{n-1} + F_{m+2}F_n = F_{m+n+1}$ to simplify the formula.
Then prove by induction using the recurrence relation for both, the Fibonacci numbers and the binomial coefficients.

Comment: I have to agree with jjagmath: there's a difference between *showing* own effort and *claiming* own effort.

Comment: I have tried to generate the formula without induction
by expressing $a_n$ in terms of '$a_0$' and '$a_1$' and the $\sum{n \choose m} $ but i didn't come to a right formula